# EXCEL VBA get raw data format with DATE() and get the date a week ago

Tags: vba, date, excel

Is it possible to get the raw data of the current date using VBA? What I'm trying to do is to get the date from one of the column and filter out the results based on last seven days. Let me show you the "date" column.

```
Parent CR Sent to IT
41824.74167
41844.66528
41842.81458
41845.57778
41845.89583
41850.83958
41869.47569
41877.46528
```

The problem is I am not allowed to alter the date in the column. I want to use autofilter to filter out last seven days of the result based on these.

```
crdata.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=9, _
            Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(Date), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(Date + 7)
```

Obviously from the code above, CLng(Date) is not working as intended and does not filter any of the rows. Any suggestions or ideas to solve it?

Comment: Code seems to be working fine. I have checked at my end. What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: @PareshJ No issues. It just never filters anything.

Comment: You have kept filter on column 9, is it the same column on which you want to apply filter??

Comment: @PareshJ column 9 is the date column shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested with your data in column A and the sub below and it filters correctly. So your code is fine but with the date of today (`mydate = Date`) I don't get any results either.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim mydate As Date
    mydate = CDate("2014-07-22")

    Tabelle1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(mydate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(mydate + 7)

End Sub
```

The problem is your provided data is

```
Parent CR      formated as date
41824.74167    2014-07-04
41844.66528    2014-07-24
41842.81458    2014-07-22
41845.57778    2014-07-25
41845.89583    2014-07-25
41850.83958    2014-07-30
41869.47569    2014-08-18
41877.46528    2014-08-26
```

- `date` means today this is `2014-12-09`.
- your filter means: Give me all dates between `2014-12-09` and `2014-12-09` + 7
- Result: Nothing, because no date is in your filter range

Comment: Isn't Date a default function?

Comment: yes `date` is the date of today. But with your data and the date of today it filters and shows no result, because no of your dates is between today and today + 7